# Inserting a formula into a cell; modify my code

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this piece of code to insert a new row, use validation on the second cell in the row:

```
Sub RICH()
'
' Macro3 Macro
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim fnd As Range
   Dim fndstr As String

   fndstr = "Targeted Premium Ads"
   Set ws = Worksheets("Inputsheet")

        Set fnd = ws.Columns(2).Find(what:=fndstr, After:=ws.Range("B11"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
        searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

            Rows(fnd.Row - 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Suppliers!$B$2:$B$178"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True



            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

However, I now want to insert two functions, say:  =sum(A$4,B$5), and =sum(A$9,  C$3) respectively into columns N, O of this newly outputted row. What would be the right approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Range("N" & fnd.Row - 2).Formula = "=SUM(A$4,B$5)"
Range("O" & fnd.Row - 2).Formula = "=SUM(A$9,C$3)"
```

(assuming `fnd.Row - 2` is the row where you want to place the formulae).

Comment: can I add those cell reference dynamically such that for each new row the cell references change?

Comment: @user1717622 Yes but you need to find a way to link the formula to the row number though. Using a formula in R1C1 coordinate (`Range(...).FormulaR1C1 = ...`) might be easier depending on your use case. To get an example of the latter: record a macro and enter a formula in a cell, it will be recorded as a R1C1 formula.